Why $\epsilon (X - X')$ and $(X - X')$ have exactly the same distribution?
Let $\epsilon \in \{-1, 1\}$ be a Rademacher random variable,
$X$ be a random variable and $X'$ be an independent copy of $X$.
Why is $\epsilon (X - X')$ and $(X - X')$ have the same distribution?
Given that $X-X'$ is symmetric around $0$, this is intuitively correct, but how to prove it?

Try to show that $\varepsilon(X  - X')$ and $X  - X'$ have the same cdf (using the definition of the cdf).

Another approach: let $Z$ be symmetric (about $0$).  Show that this alone suffices to show that $Z$ and $\epsilon Z$ have the same distribution when $\epsilon$ is independent of $Z.$  (I believe this more clearly reveals the essence of the problem.)

You probably need to add the condition that $\epsilon$ and $X$ are independent, otherwise the conclusion may not hold.  For example, if $X, X' \text{ i.i.d. } \sim N(0, 1)$, $\epsilon = 2I_{\{X - X' > ~0\}} - 1$. Since $X - X' \sim N(0, 2)$, on one hand, $P(X - X' \leq 1) = \Phi(1/\sqrt{2})$. On the other hand,
\begin{align*}
P(\epsilon(X - X') \leq 1) &= P(X - X' \leq 1, X - X' > 0) + P(X - X' \geq -1, X - X' \leq 0) \\
&= P(0 < X - X' \leq 1) + P(-1 \leq X - X' \leq 0) \\
&= \Phi(1/\sqrt{2}) - \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2} - \Phi(-1/\sqrt{2}) \\
&= 2\Phi(1/\sqrt{2}) - 1 \neq \Phi(1/\sqrt{2}). 
\end{align*}
When $\epsilon$ and $X$ are assumed independent, the conclusion indeed holds: as for any $x \in \mathbb{R}$,
\begin{align*}
P(\epsilon(X - X') \leq x) &= P(X - X' \leq x, \epsilon = 1) + P(X - X' \geq -x, \epsilon = -1) \\
&= P(X - X' \leq x)P(\epsilon = 1) + P(X - X' \geq -x)P(\epsilon = -1) \\
&= \frac{1}{2}P(X - X' \leq x) + \frac{1}{2}P(X - X' \geq -x) \\
&= P(X - X' \leq x).  
\end{align*}
The last equality holds because if $F$ is the common distribution function of $X$ and $X'$, then
\begin{align*}
& P(X - X' \leq x) = \int_{\mathbb{R}}P(X - t \leq x)~\mathrm dF(t) = \int_{\mathbb{R}}F(x + t)~\mathrm dF(t), \\
& P(X - X' \geq -x) = \int_{\mathbb{R}}P(t - X' \geq -x)~\mathrm dF(t) = \int_{\mathbb{R}}F(x + t)~\mathrm dF(t). \\
\end{align*}

The counter-example construction is pretty dope. Good catch. +1.

I offer this answer to make several points:

There's nothing special about $X-X^\prime$ except it is symmetric.

The result applies even when $\epsilon$ is not a Rademacher variable, which by definition is symmetric, but also when it's an asymmetric distribution supported on $\pm 1.$

It requires nothing more than the fundamental axioms of probability and the definition of independence to prove.  I highlight the places where these axioms and the definition are invoked.

It is (therefore) unnecessary to invoke integration or densities of any sort, because the result is purely about probabilities.



Let $Z$ be a random variable with a symmetric distribution.  This means $Z$ and $-Z$ have the same distribution.
Suppose $\epsilon$ is a variable independent of $Z$ having only $\pm 1$ as possible values with associated probabilities $p_{\pm 1}.$  Let $x$ be any real number (that is, any possible argument of a cumulative distribution function). As a shorthand notation, given any logical predicate $\mathcal P(Z,\epsilon),$ let $\{\mathcal P(Z,\epsilon)\}$ be a shorthand for the event where $\mathcal P$ is true.  With this in mind, consider the event $\{\epsilon Z \le x\}:$
$$\{\epsilon Z \le x\} = \{\epsilon=1\}\cap \{(1)Z\le x\}\quad  \bigcup\quad   \{\epsilon = -1\} \cap \{(-1)Z \le x\}.$$
(I have taken the liberty of using "$1$" in place of "$\epsilon$" in the first subset and "$-1$" in its place in the second subset: justifying this is strictly a matter of elementary set theory.)
This decomposition is disjoint because $\epsilon$ has a different value in each subset, whence the probabilities of these events sum to the original probability.  Because $\epsilon$ and $Z$ are independent, probabilities associated with each variable separately will simply multiply.  In effect, we may replace events by their probabilities, "$\cap$" by "$\times,$" and "$\cup$" by "$+.$"  Consequently, using the standard $F_X$ notation for probability functions $F_X(x)=\Pr(X\le x),$ we have
$$\begin{aligned}
F_{\epsilon Z}(x) = \Pr(\{\epsilon Z \le x\}) &= p_1 F_Z(x) +p_{-1}F_{-Z}(x)\\
&= p_1 F_{-Z}(x) + p_{-1} F_{-Z}(x)\\
&= (p_1+p_{-1})F_{-Z}(x)\\
&= F_{-Z}(x).
\end{aligned}$$
The second line uses the assumption that $Z$ and $-Z$ have the same distribution while the last line uses the axiom of total probability.
When $X$ and $X^\prime$ are iid, $Z = X-X^\prime$ has the same distribution as $-Z = X^\prime - X$ (because the two expressions merely switch the labels of the two random variables referenced by $X$ and $X^\prime$). The result is immediate: $\epsilon(X-X^\prime)$ and $X^\prime - X$ have the same distribution, QED.

You can weaken the conditions to $(X,X´)$ is just exchangeable -- meaning that $(X,X´)\sim(X´,X)$ -- and $\epsilon$ is any random variable, independent of $(X,X´)$, with support $\{-1,1\}$. Then, writing $g(u,v)=u-v$, we have
\begin{align}
  P(X-X´\in B)&=P(g(X,X´)\in B) \\
  &=P((X,X´)\in g^{-1}(B)) \\
  &=P((X´,X)\in g^{-1}(B)) \qquad \text{(exchangeability)} \\
  &=P(g(X´,X)\in B) \\
  &=P(X´-X\in B),
\end{align}
implying that $X-X´\sim X´-X$. The remaining argument is exactly like in the other answers: just condition on $\epsilon$, use Total Probability, and remember the independence between $\epsilon$ and $(X,X´)$. In this way,
\begin{align}
  P(\epsilon(X-X´)\in B) &= P(X-X´\in B\mid \epsilon=1)P(\epsilon=1) \\
&\qquad + P(X´-X\in B\mid\epsilon=-1)P(\epsilon=-1) \\
  &= P(X-X´\in B)P(\epsilon=1) +
P(X´-X\in B)P(\epsilon=-1) \\
  &= P(X-X´\in B)\left\{P(\epsilon=1) + P(\epsilon=-1)\right\} \\
  &= P(X-X´\in B),
\end{align}
yielding the desired result: $\epsilon(X-X´)\sim X-X´$.
